# Make the JSON object empty again

Tags: json

When I get the data thru socket in node js, I use the data and before writing new data to that  JSON, I need to delete some parts of it, but there is too many different things would be deleted. I want to make JSON object clear, erase everything before start adding anything to it.
So I have tried something like:

```
JSON_object = {}; // does nothing
JSON_object = null; // error
JSON_object.empty(); // error...
```

and so on..

Nothing works.

Does any1 know how to make it empty?

Comment: A JSON object which is literally `{}` is as close to empty as you get.

Comment: What is your language??

Comment: JSON in nodejs server app.
I don't know why, but = {} does nothing.

Comment: client is AS3 if that make any difference.

Comment: I said *literally*, as in the JSON character string, not the program object.  If you're creating a program object (in whatever language nodejs is) you probably need to do something like `new JSONObject`.

Comment: Or (after figuring out you're using JavaScript) `new Object()`.

Comment: (You should know what language you're using.)

Comment: TY man, I guess the problem is solved, as you said, {} it is. I copied JSON data to that object you said, then I could empty like this JSON = {} and use the data after from new object. Then wrote the data to empty JSON, just like I wanted. So simple.